# peculiar behaviour of dynamically generated mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

What started out yesterday as the beginnings of an answer for, or improvements to, code found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832710/how-to-fix-sql-entries-not-being-displayed-in-datatables#comment102100380_57832710) has now become something of an enigma. I cannot figure why the dynamically generated query produces different results to the equivilent when run in the mysqli client or even when written out in php as a standard prepared statement ( losing the dynamic element )

For anyone wishing to experiment I included the table schema and dummy records.

The dynamic query is built based upon existence of certain variables ( these would, in the original question, have been POST variables ) but here are static - though they can be negated by commenting them out which will in turn affect the WHERE clause that is generated.

```
<style>
    body, body *{font-size:0.85rem;}
    h1,h2{font-size:0.95rem;text-decoration:underline}
    pre{white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;}
</style>
<?php

    /*

    to create a suitable table and populate with dummy data

    create table `volopp` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
        `taskname` varchar(50) not null default '0',
        `industryname` varchar(50) not null default '0',
        `country` varchar(50) not null default '0',
        `orgname` varchar(50) not null default '0',
        `photo` varchar(50) not null default '0',
        primary key (`id`)
    )
    engine=innodb;

    insert into `volopp` (`id`, `taskname`, `industryname`, `description`, `country`, `orgname`, `photo`, `status`) values
        (1, 'squirrel juggling', 'outdoor pursuits', 'squirrels are members of the family sciuridae, a family that includes small or medium-size rodents. the squirrel family includes tree squirrels, ground squirrels, chipmunks, marmots, flying squirrels, and prairie dogs amongst other rodents.', 'scotland', 'squirrel jugglers association', 'squirrel.jpg', 1),
        (2, 'hedgehog pickling', 'food and drink', 'a hedgehog is any of the spiny mammals of the subfamily erinaceinae, in the eulipotyphlan family erinaceidae. there are seventeen species of hedgehog in five genera found through parts of europe, asia, and africa, and in new zealand by introduction.', 'england', 'hog heaven association', 'hedgehog.jpg', 0),
        (3, 'haggis hunting', 'outdoor pursuits', 'wild haggis is a creature of scottish folklore, said to be native to the scottish highlands. it is comically claimed to be the source of haggis, a traditional scottish dish that is in fact made from the innards of sheep.', 'scotland', 'campbell\'s haggis hunt', 'lesser-haggis.jpg', 1),
        (4, 'nessie netting', 'outdoor pursuits', 'the loch ness monster or nessie is said to be a creature that inhabits loch ness in the scottish highlands. it is often described as large in size with a long neck and one or more humps protruding from the water.', 'scotland', 'nessienets.org.uk', 'loch-ness.jpg', 0),
        (5, 'dwarf tossing', 'outdoor pursuits', 'dwarf-tossing, also called midget-tossing, is a pub/bar attraction in which people with dwarfism, wearing special padded clothing or velcro costumes, are thrown onto mattresses or at velcro-coated walls. participants compete to throw the person with dwarfism the farthest.', 'scotland', 'highlandgames.scot', 'highland-games.jpg', 1),
        (6, 'stickleback stuffing', 'indoor pursuits', 'sticklebacks are small, elongated fishes that reach a maximum length of about 18 cm (7 inches). the members of the family are characterized by a row of 2 to 16 spines on the back, which are positioned in front of a soft-rayed dorsal fin.', 'wales', 'stickleback.org', 'spinysucker.jpg', 0),
        (7, 'squirrel suckling', 'historic pastimes', 'tree rats', 'ireland', 'weirdness abounds', 'treerat.gif', 0);


    For reference
    +----+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+--------+
    | id | taskname             | industryname      | description        | country  | orgname                       | photo              | status |
    +----+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+--------+
    |  1 | squirrel juggling    | outdoor pursuits  | Squirrels are m... | scotland | Squirrel Jugglers Association | squirrel.jpg       |      1 |
    |  2 | Hedgehog Pickling    | food and drink    | A hedgehog is a... | england  | Hog Heaven Association        | hedgehog.jpg       |      0 |
    |  3 | Haggis Hunting       | outdoor pursuits  | Wild haggis is ... | scotland | Campbell's Haggis Hunt        | lesser-haggis.jpg  |      1 |
    |  4 | Nessie Netting       | outdoor pursuits  | The Loch Ness M... | scotland | NessieNets.org.uk             | Loch-Ness.jpg      |      0 |
    |  5 | Dwarf Tossing        | outdoor pursuits  | Dwarf-tossing, ... | scotland | highlandgames.scot            | highland-games.jpg |      1 |
    |  6 | Stickleback Stuffing | indoor pursuits   | Sticklebacks ar... | wales    | stickleback.org               | spinyfucker.jpg    |      0 |
    |  7 | squirrel suckling    | historic pastimes | tree rats...       | ireland  | weirdness abounds             | treerat.gif        |      0 |
    +----+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+--------+


    */

    /*
        utility functions to try to assist debugging
    */
    function pre( $data, $header ){
        $title = $header ? sprintf( '<h1>%s</h1>', $header ) : '';
        printf( '<pre>%s%s</pre>', $title, print_r($data,true) );
    }
    function preview_mysqli( $sql, $args ){
        $index=0;
        for( $i=0; $i < strlen( $sql ); $i++ ){
            $char = substr( $sql, $i, 1 );
            if( $char == '?' ) {
                $param = $args[ $index ];
                if( !strstr( $param, '"' ) )$param=sprintf( '"%s"', $param );
                $sql = substr_replace( $sql, $param, $i, 1 );
                $index++;
            }
        }
        return preg_replace( '@(\t)@', ' ', $sql );
    }
    function varname( $var ){
        foreach( $GLOBALS as $name => $value )if( $value === $var ) return $name;
        return false;
    }
    /*
        This writes out the equivilent php code one would use
        to run the query manually without generating on the fly.
        This produces different results but is, I'm sure, essentially
        the same query being executed.
    */
    function preview_mysqli_statement( $sql, $args ){
        $types=array();
        foreach( $args as $arg )$types[]=type( $arg );
        $vars=array();
        foreach( $args as $arg )$vars[]=sprintf( '$%s', varname( $arg ) );
        return preg_replace('@\t@',' ',sprintf('
            $sql="%s";

            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param( "%s", %s );
            $res=$stmt->execute();
            if( $res ){
                $res=$stmt->get_result();
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                    pre( $rs, "-- record --" );
                }
            }',
            $sql,
            implode( '', $types ),
            implode( ', ', $vars )
        ));
    }
    /* 
        utility to return string for the variable type 
        used when creating the statement binding 
    */
    function type($arg){
        switch( gettype( $arg ) ){
            case 'integer':
            case 'int': return 'i';
            case 'float':
            case 'double': return 'd';
            default: return 's';
        }
    }








    /* standard db connection */
    $dbhost =   '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );



    /* parameters used to generate where clause. Comment out to negate and modify query */
    $search_taskname='squirrel';
    $search_industry='outdoor pursuits';
    $search_country='scotland';
    $search_orgname='association';
    $search_description='folklore';

    /* placeholders */
    $where=array();
    $args=array();
    $types=array();


    /* Clause joining verb : AND | OR */
    $joiner='or';

    /* create where clause conditions */
    if( !empty( $search_taskname ) ){
        $where[]='`taskname` like ?';
        $search_taskname="%{$search_taskname}%";
        $args[]=$search_taskname;
    }

    if( !empty( $search_industry ) ){
        $where[]='`industryname`=?';
        $args[]=$search_industry;
    }

    if( !empty( $search_country ) ){
        $where[]='`country`=?';
        $args[]=$search_country;
    }

    if( !empty( $search_orgname ) ){
        $where[]='`orgname` like ?';
        $search_orgname="%{$search_orgname}%";
        $args[]=$search_orgname;
    }

    if( !empty( $search_description ) ){
        $where[]='`description` like ?';
        $search_description="%{$search_description}%";
        $args[]=$search_description;
    }

    if( isset( $search_status ) ){
        $where[]='`status`=?';
        $args[]=$search_status;
    }

    if( count( $where )==0 )exit('bad foo: no "WHERE" clause parameters');

    /* construct the full SQL statement with full where clauses */
    $sql=sprintf('select id,taskname,industryname,country,orgname,photo,status
        from `volopp`
        %s;', 
        count( $where ) > 0 ? sprintf( 'where %s', implode( sprintf( ' %s ', $joiner ), $where ) ) : ''
    );
    $params=&$args;



    $types=array();
    foreach( $params as $param )$types[]=type( $param );
    $types=implode( '', $types );



    /* debug statements */
    pre( preg_replace( '@\t@', ' ', $sql ), 'The generated sql statement to be passed to `prepare` method.' );
    pre( preview_mysqli( $sql, $params ), 'Effective query: Can be run in mysql client' );
    pre( preview_mysqli_statement( $sql, $params ), 'Generated php code to emulate the whole process. [copy]' );




    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    if( $stmt ){
        $vars=array();
        $vars[]=&$types;

        foreach( $params as $param ) $vars[]=&$param;

        $callback=array(  $stmt, 'bind_param' );
        call_user_func_array( $callback, $vars );


        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if( $result ){
            $result=$stmt->get_result();

            $i=1;
            while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
                pre( $rs, sprintf(' --> Live record %d', $i ) );
                $i++;
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }


    /*
        if you copy the generated php code from debug output
        and run... it should run and produce different 
        results.
    */


?>
```

---

[image: Results showing single record from query run dynamically]
The above screenshot shows 1 record returned when script is run with default parameters.

[image: Same query run in mysql client]

Running the generated PHP code version, as below, yields the same results as when run in the mysql client ( see above screenshot ).

```
<?php

    $dbhost =   '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    function pre( $data, $header ){
        $title = $header ? sprintf( '<h1>%s</h1>', $header ) : '';
        printf( '<pre>%s%s</pre>', $title, print_r($data,true) );
    }


    $search_taskname='squirrel';
    $search_industry='outdoor pursuits';
    $search_country='scotland';
    $search_orgname='association';
    $search_description='folklore';

    /* clauses that use `like` */
    $search_taskname="%{$search_taskname}%";
    $search_orgname="%{$search_orgname}%";
    $search_description="%{$search_description}%";


    $sql="select id,taskname,industryname,country,orgname,photo,status
            from `volopp`
        where `taskname` like ? or `industryname`=? or `country`=? or `orgname` like ? or `description` like ?;";

    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param( "sssss", $search_taskname, $search_industry, $search_country, $search_orgname, $search_description );
    $res=$stmt->execute();

    if( $res ){
       $res=$stmt->get_result();
       while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
           pre( $rs, "-- record --" );
       }
    }

?>
```

[image: Results from generated PHP and statically typed prepared statement]

Sorry for the long post. If anyone can figure out what is going on I'd be happy to hear. No doubt I have missed something obvious and will feel stupid someone points out a glaring oops.

Comment: Did you try `echo $sql; exit;` to see, what has been generated?

Comment: yes, the sql that is generated looks good ~ as can be seen in the screenshots

Comment: intrigued by the downvote - because it was too long or what??

Comment: Almost 20K rep - And you post low quality sceenshots of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the segment...

```
if( $stmt ){
     $vars=array();
     $vars[]=&$types;

     foreach( $params as $param ) $vars[]=&$param;

     $callback=array(  $stmt, 'bind_param' );

     print_r($vars);

     call_user_func_array( $callback, $vars );
```

The output of which is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => sssss
    [1] => %folklore%
    [2] => %folklore%
    [3] => %folklore%
    [4] => %folklore%
    [5] => %folklore%
)
```

To make this call easier, I would tend to use splat anyway...

```
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
```

which gives you the output you want (I think).

Comment: perfect - thanks for finding that! I had looked at but then not used the `splat` operator ~ it sure is soo much easier using that than the convoluted `call_user_func_array` approach. Inside that loop (`foreach( $params as $param )` the `$param` var is correct but the reference that is added to $vars is wrong... hey ho. Thanks @Nigel!